# which drive to add my operating system to?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have a Lenovo desktop that loads slowly at startup. I am going to add an SSD to it. Should I transfer all items from my HDD to SSD, or just the operating system? The SSD is 500 GB and my hard drive is a lot less, 1863 GB. The computer only runs really slow when it is loading up, I have a few extra SSD and just thought installing one of them might help, but now sure which drive to install the operating system on, or all my other websites, virus program, etc.   Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1863 GB is more than 3x the size of your SSD.  There no way to image a 2 TB HDD to a 500 GB SSD.  You are better off just reinstalling Windows and backing your files to flash storage in order to transfer them to your SSD.

Answer (score 2):

To fully use the SSD, boot and Windows and installed programs
should both be on it.

Because of the size differences between the disks,
the strategy to use depends on the amount of *used space* on the
current disk:

- If the used space is less than, say, 450 GB, then just clone
  the disk to the SSD using a product that supports size differences
  (example
  [AOMEI Backupper Standard](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html))
- If the used space is a little more than this amount, try to offload
  enough data so it fits into the SSD
- If the used space is much more than that, replace the hard disk by
  the SSD in the computer, install Windows and your applications,
  then add the HDD as a second disk (clean it up when everything
  works to your satisfaction).